# Easiest way to set highScore in Game Center?

Tags: game-center, sprite-kit

I know this is a vague question but is there any code you could point me to? I have trouble understanding Apple Documentation. A tutorial or someone explaining the code would be great. I have a Sprite Kit game that stores a high score variable in an int. What would be the easiest way to add that into Game Center? Even if you can't provide code for it, could you just lay out the steps that I would need in order to do this.

Comment: try google, there are many GC tutorials...

Answer (score 1):

You could google "Game Center Tutorial iOS 7" and get something like this in your search results :

http://maniacdev.com/2011/05/tutorial-game-center-basics-leaderboards-and-achievements

imagine that. :)